# Using full join to match values in two different dataframes

Tags: r, join, merge, match

I have two dataframes.The first data frame consists of four columns 1) ID, 2) Site, 3) Depth, and 4) Density. The second dataframe consists of 1) ID 2) Site, and 3) Choice.

df1

```
  ID Sites Depth Density
  1     B   0.2       0
  2     B   0.2       1
  3     D   0.3       0
  4     D   0.3       1
  5     B   0.2       2
```

df2

```
  ID Sites Choice 
  1     A    No
  1     B    Yes     
  1     C    No
  1     D    No
  2     A    No
  2     B    Yes
  2     C    No
  2     D    No
  3     A    No
  3     B    No
  3     C    No
  3     D    Yes
  4     A    No
  4     B    No
  4     C    No
  4     D    Yes
  5     A    No
  5     B    Yes
  5     C    No
  5     D    No
```

What I am trying to do is add a column to df2 that has the densities in each site when the ID has a "Yes". Below is what I want the output to be:

Desired Output

```
  ID Sites Choice Depth  Density
  1     A    No     0.1     0
  1     B    Yes    0.2     0 
  1     C    No     0.3     0 
  1     D    No     0.4     0
  2     A    No     0.1     0
  2     B    Yes    0.2     1
  2     C    No     0.3     0
  2     D    No     0.4     0
  3     A    No     0.1     0
  3     B    No     0.2     1
  3     C    No     0.3     0
  3     D    Yes    0.4     0
  4     A    No     0.1     0
  4     B    No     0.2     1
  4     C    No     0.3     0
  4     D    Yes    0.4     1
  5     A    No     0.1     0
  5     B    Yes    0.2     2
  5     C    No     0.3     0
  5     D    No     0.4     1
```

I've tried using the following but it doesn't work:

```
     df3<-df2 %>%
     full_join(df1, by = c("ID", "Sites")) %>%
     group_by(ID) %>%
     mutate(Density = Density[Choice == "Yes"]) %>%
     distinct(ID, Sites, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Thank you for your help, stackoverflow community.

Comment: Where did `Depth = 0.1` come from when ID = 1 and Sites = A? I don't see it in either table.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
df1<-data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                Sites = c("B", "B", "D", "D", "B"),
                Depth = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2),
                Density = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 2)
)

df2<-data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5),
                Sites = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D",
                          "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D"),
                Choice = c("No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No",
                           "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No",
                           "No")
)

df3<-df2 %>%
  left_join(df1, by = c("ID", "Sites")) %>%
  mutate(Density=if_else(Choice=="Yes",Density, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Data.

```
  df1 <- data.frame(
      ID = seq(from = 1, to = 5, by = 1),
      Sites = c("B", "B", "D", "D", "B"),
      Depth = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2),
      Density = c(0,1,0,1,2)
    )

qw <- c("No", "Yes")
  
df2 <- data.frame(
  ID = c(rep(1:5, times = 5)),
  Sites = sample(LETTERS[1:4], size = 25, replace = TRUE),
  Choice = sample(qw, size = 25, replace = T)
)
```

But I am slightly confused by what you need from this reprex. Your statement makes it seem that you want a subsetted DF3, which only contains records where CHOICE == "YES" is TRUE, and ID = ID, and Site = Site. Obviously this will result in very few records.

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = c("Sites", "ID")) %>% 
filter(Choice == "Yes") # only one record from the dummy data.
```

If the Choice 'Yes' is a property of the ID, but not Site, here is an option.

```
df3 <- df1 %>% 
select(-Sites) %>% 
  left_join(df2 %>% filter(Choice == "Yes"), by = "ID")
```

I guess I am just confused whether both Sites and ID's need to match. If so their are just not many records here.

Answer (score 0):

A data.table solution:

```
df1[df2[ID %in% df2[Choice == "Yes", unique(ID)], ], 
    on = .(ID, Sites)][is.na(Density), 
                           Density := 0][]
```

### What is in there:

- `df2[Choice == "Yes", unique(ID)` filters where choice is yes and returns unique IDs. We'll need them to filter `df2`.
- `df2[ID %in% df2[Choice == "Yes", unique(ID)], ]` filters only the cases where ID matches the IDs where there is at least one "yes" in choices.
- `df1[df_x, on = .(ID, Sites)]` makes a left join of `df1` with whatever is in `df_x` (in our case, the filtered `df2`.
- `[is.na(Density), Density := 0]` filters the rows where Density is `NA` and only in those rows assigns 0 to Density.
- `[]` Prints to screen the resuling data, you don't really need it.